# Volume of a pyramid with equilateral triangle as base

Tags: geometry

> The base of a right pyramid is an equilateral triangle of side 4cm
>   each. Each slant edge is 5cm long. The volume of pyramid is

For this question,

> answer provided by [sscadda.com](http://www.sscadda.com/2015/05/ssc-cgl-2015-polity-quiz.html) is $\dfrac{20}{3}\sqrt{3}$ *(see comments section at bottom)*

(a) But this may be wrong because volume is $\dfrac{1}{3}×\text{base}×\text{height}$ and in the solution, slant edge is used in place of height. Am I correct here?

(b) So, for correct solution, we may need to first find height and then use the formula volume is $\dfrac{1}{3}×\text{base}×\text{height}$ , am I correct?

(c) Is the the volume is $\dfrac{4\sqrt{59}}{3}$ as provided in [careerbless.com](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=2498)? If this approach is right, is there any shortcut formula for the same?

(d) If none of my comments is right, please guide how to handle this kind of a question.

Comment: I think you're correct in (a). That is a bad mistake. I get that the pyramid's height is $\;\frac{\sqrt{209}}3\;$

Comment: @Joanpemo , please share your steps.

Comment: By "right pyramid", do you mean that one of  the edges is perpendicular to the base?

Comment: The answer should be $\frac 43 \sqrt{59}$. The elementary approach is best, the height of the pyramid intersects the base at the centroid of the base, so use the $2:1$ ratio and Pythagoras to figure out one of the catheti of the right triangle with the slant edge as its hypotenuse. This allows you to determine the height of the pyramid by another application of Pythagoras. It's all smooth sailing from there. I assume you know how to work this approach but if you want a full answer, let me know.

Comment: @robjohn A right pyramid is one where the apex lies directly (vertically) over the centroid of the base. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RightPyramid.html

Comment: @Deepak: Thanks for answering.  In the year since I posted the comment, I looked up and found the definition, but it's good to have this in a comment at least.  I might amend the question.

Comment: @robjohn I honestly didn't realise it was an old question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), the area of the base is
$$
\Delta=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=\sqrt{6(6-4)(6-4)(6-4)}=4\sqrt3
$$
so the [radius of the circumcircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Other_properties) is
$$
R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}=\frac{4\cdot4\cdot4}{4\cdot4\sqrt3}=\frac4{\sqrt3}
$$
[The Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) says that the altitude of the pyramid is
$$
h=\sqrt{5^2-R^2}=\sqrt{25-\frac{16}3}=\sqrt{\frac{59}3}
$$
The volume is therefore
$$
V=\frac13\Delta h=\frac43\sqrt{59}
$$

Answer (score 0):

@Kiran An equilateral triangle's area is $\;\frac{\sqrt3}4s^2\;$ , with $\;s=$ the triangle's side, and then he center of the triangle is of length $\;\frac s{\sqrt3}\;$ , so taking the straight triangle formed by the pyramid's apex, the center of the base triangle and one of the vertices, the height is, by Pythagoras:

$$\sqrt{T^2-\frac{s^2}3}\;\;,\;\;\;\;T=\text{ the slanted's pyramid's side's length}$$

Now input $\;s=4\;,\;\;T=5\;$$ in the above

Comment: with T=5 AND s=4, we get height as $\dfrac{\sqrt{59}}{\sqrt{3}}$, right?